# Elasticsearch Multiple Prefix query OR Matching

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to accomplish the following task (expressed as an equivalent SQL query)

```
WHERE field1 LIKE 'FOO%' OR field2 LIKE 'FOO%'
```

But say `boost` field2 (i.e. if a document just 1 out of two fields) the document who matched field2 is boosted

How do I accomplish this in Elasticsearch? I've scoured the documentation endlessly and just keep getting more confused

I've tried:

```
POST securities/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1, 
      "should": [
        {
            "match_phrase_prefix": {
              "field2": "FOO"
            }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase_prefix": {
              "field2": "FOO"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

but there is no way I can specify boost from within **bool.should[*].match_phrase_prefix**

I see there is a **boost** property that I can specify at the **bool** level, but I am not sure how that is applied

Comment: You have "field2" 2 times in your example. I think the first one should be "field1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make it work, you should change this:

```
"match_phrase_prefix": {
    "field2": "FOO"
}
```

to this:

```
"match_phrase_prefix": {
    "field2": {
        "value": "FOO",
        "boost": 2.0
    }
}
```

This should be a proper syntax for boosting.

Comment: I see that boost was added in a 2015 PR, somehow not part of Kibana's autocomplete thank you!